# What weight of Weighing scale bars shop keeper should buy?

Tags: mathematics, weighing

Story:

Years ago there was a poor shop keeper who had a small amount of money enough to buy only FOUR weight bars for his an old weigh scale. Now the problem is he can buy only FOUR weight bars and he has to deal with customers who buy 1 to 40 Kilograms goods from his shop so **What weight of Weighing scale bars shop keeper should buy**?

[image]

**Rules** :

1. Shop Kipper can't weight goods for one customer more than once like: If the customer wants to buy 20 KG apple Kipper can't weight 10KG + 10KG twice.
2. The total weight of all 4 weight bar should be 40 neither more nor less.

**Source**: Grandma :)

Comment: 1,3,9,27? If so, it is here somewhere. If you want 2 for example, u add 3 to one side and 1 to other. And so on. For 5 for example is 9 to one side and -4 to other.

Answer (score 2):

'What weight of Weighing scale bars shop keeper should buy?'

> **40kg Total.**
>  **1 x 27kg,1 x 9kg, 1 x 3kg and 1 x 1kg.**

This is because:

> You can switch the weights to either side (not just opposite the produce). For example if you want to weigh 14kg of produce you would put 27kg on one side and the other 3 (totalling 13kg) on the side with the produce :)

Comment: Correct, it was very quick.

Comment: @GovindPrajapati I did this in school, in fact I'm going to ask my kids tonight :)